# acts_as_taggable_on and rails autocomplete gem - displaying tag counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using the acts_as_taggable_on gem and the rails jquery autocomplete gem

I know how to get the tag counts via the gem

I know that in order to display something else other than the return search results for the autocomplete I need to do something like this

```
autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag', :full => true
```

and adding 2 more keys which are

```
:extra_data , :display_value
```

the extra data will retrieve the more data in the search (not sure it is needed here)
the display_value will call a method from within the model which is searched with the autocomplete.

**The problem:**

I don't know where to put the method for the display_value which should be something like

```
def tags_with_counts
 "#{tag.name} x #{tag.count}
end
```

As I don't have a tag model file to put it in (since the acts_as_taggable_on does not generate such file.

But even if I did have such file, from previous experiments, that method can only use data that is retrieved with the autocomplete search, and I don't have a column with tag counts.

What do I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by doing

> ```
> class Tag < ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
>
>
>   def tagcount
>        num = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(:tag_id => self.id).count
>        "#{Tag.find(self.id).name} x #{num}"
>   end
>
>
> end
> ```

and sending the "Tag" class to the rails-autocomplete call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you include the `acts_as_taggable` directive in one of your models you're essentially opening it up to a series of methods and relationships belonging to the acts-as-taggable-on module. With that said if you're wanting to add a method that is in scope of your acts-as-taggable-on module then you would simply define it in the same model.

For example:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_taggable

  def tags_with_counts
   "#{tag.name} x #{tag.count}"
  end

end
```

FYI your tags_with_counts method was missing a closing double-quote.

Comment: this doesn't work since rails-autocomplete needs it to be a method within the return model (which is the tag). How do I insert that method to be part of the model?